# UFW Masquerade and outside traffic only on specific interfaces

Tags: iptables, ufw, wireguard

I have a Ubuntu system (192.168.A.B) that is running as a Wireguard "server" with 2 tunnels with the following networks and UFW rules:

Network 10.255.200.0/24

```
ufw allow XXX/udp && ufw route allow in on wg200 out on any && ufw route allow in on wg200 out on eth0 && ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg200
```

Network 10.255.245.0/24

```
ufw allow YYY/udp && ufw route allow in on wg245 out on wg245 to any from any && ufw route reject in on wg245 out on any to any from any
```

I have added the following to /etc/ufw/before.rules to allow devices in the 10.255.200.0/24 network to reach outside of the host

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.255.200.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

That seems to work, but now I need to allow other hosts in the host's network (192.168.A.0/24) to be able to reach systems in the 10.255.245.0/24 network without that network being able to reach by default to 192.168.A.0/24.

What UFW rules do I need to use to still keep the host network secure and also to keep the WG network separated as much as can be? Also, is there a better way to do masquerading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your question description and the UFW rules you've set up, it looks to me like you want to allow your WireGuard server to do these 4 things?:

1. Forward connections between any two hosts on its wg200 network.
2. Masquerade connections from any host on its wg200 network to any host on its eth0 network.
3. Forward connections between any two hosts on its wg245 network.
4. Masquerade connections from any host on its eth0 network to any host on its wg245 network.

If these are the only 4 things you want to allow, then these are the only UFW route rules you need:

```
ufw route allow in on wg200 out on wg200
ufw route allow in on wg200 out on eth0
ufw route allow in on wg245 out on wg245
ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg245
```

Plus you need to add a second `MASQUERADE` rule to your `/etc/ufw/before.rules` (if you want to masquerade #4):

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.255.200.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.A.0/24 -o wg245 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

---

Note that UFW automatically sets up these two things for you:

1. UFW uses connection tracking to allow the destination of connections that have been forwarded in one direction to reply back to the connection's initial source (so you only need to specify rules for the "forward" direction, and not the "reverse" direction).
2. UFW blocks all forwarded connections except those you've specifically allowed (so you don't need to reject things that you haven't explicitly allowed).

So to be picky about your existing route rules:

```
(1) ufw route allow in on wg200 out on any
(2) ufw route allow in on wg200 out on eth0
(3) ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg200
(4) ufw route allow in on wg245 out on wg245 to any from any
(5) ufw route reject in on wg245 out on any to any from any
```

- (1) & (2) are redundant -- you don't need (2) if you have (1) -- but (1) also allows any host in wg200 to connect to any host in wg245 (not sure if you want that?)
- (3) is only needed if you want to allow hosts from your eth0 network to *initiate* new connections to your wg200 network; if hosts from your eth0 network are always on the receiving end of connections from your wg200 network (which is likely given you're masquerading from wg200 to eth0), then you don't need this rule
- `to any from any` is unneeded on (4)
- (5) is unneeded

Comment: Thank you, Justin!
I have applied the before.rules and changed the UFW definitions and now the network is accessible. Also, thank you for your picky suggestions, they are much appreciated and applied. I didn't really think of the redundancy and necessity of some of them.